# Javascript - Create AWS SQS Subscriber

Tags: javascript, amazon-sqs

Dear Folks that are smarter than me (everyone). I'm trying to use NodeJS to pull AWS SQS every 20 seconds (long pulling). Once it does pull a message the function will transcode a video that can take up to 5 minutes to complete.

**The problem:** I don't want to pull AWS SQS if I'm still processing a video. So, I need my setInterval function to skip the aws.SQS.recieveMessage function IF my promise is not resolved. Anyone know a good way to do this?

Here is my horrible test to see if I can get the concepts down (does not work):

```js
// Quick Testbed
let asyncthingy = asyncCall();
const testTimer = () => {
    if (!asyncthingy.promise){
        asyncthingy = asyncCall();
    }
    console.log("I executed the specified function");
}

function resolveAfter4Seconds() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('resolved');
        },4000);
    });
}

async function asyncCall() {
    console.log("I'm the async call");
    let result = await resolveAfter4Seconds();
}

setInterval(testTimer, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around and giving up with the idea of a native way to check the promise status, I ended up setting the status manually. If anyone can find a better way of doing this please share. Below is the cleaned up test code that should also be much more clear.

```js
// Quick Testbed
var transcoderstatus = 0;

async function startSQSListener() {
    if (!transcoderstatus){
        transcoderstatus = 1;
        let result = await checkSQSQueue();
        transcodeVideo();
    }
    //console.log("Transcoder Status: ",transcoderstatus);
}

function checkSQSQueue() {
    console.log("Checking SQS Queue");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Pulled new message");
            resolve('resolved');
        },2000);
    });
}

function transcodeVideo() {
    transcoderstatus = 1;
    console.log("Transcoding Video");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            transcoderstatus = 0;
            console.log("Transcoding completed");
            console.log("---------------");
            resolve('resolved');
        },10000);
    });
}

setInterval(startSQSListener, 1500);
```